# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - SimpleXML

Tags: xmlparser, php

Всем, привет! Помогите, пожалуйста найти ошибку.

Выполняю Парсинг XML-документа с помощью [SimpleXML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-simplexml/).

**Структура XML-документа:**

```
<PEOPLE_CATALOG NUM="777" DATE="11.07.2013" ID="789654321"> 
 <PEOPLE>
  <PEOPLE_NAME>Тест Тестович Тестов</PEOPLE_NAME>
  <NUM>1</NUM>
  <PERSON_TYPE>11</PERSON_TYPE>
  <DESCRIPTION>Нуда нуда</DESCRIPTION>
  <ID>123456</ID>
 </PEOPLE>
 <PEOPLE>
 <PEOPLE_NAME>Тест Тестович Тестов</PEOPLE_NAME>
  <NUM>1</NUM>
  <PERSON_TYPE>12</PERSON_TYPE>
  <DESCRIPTION>Нуда нуда</DESCRIPTION>
  <ID>1234567</ID>
 </PEOPLE>
 <PEOPLE>
 <PEOPLE_NAME>Тест Тестович Тестов</PEOPLE_NAME>
  <NUM>1</NUM>
  <PERSON_TYPE>13</PERSON_TYPE>
  <DESCRIPTION>Нуда нуда</DESCRIPTION>
  <ID>12345678</ID>
 </PEOPLE>
</PEOPLE_CATALOG>
```

**Выполняю итерации через элементы как описано в мануале:**

```
$res = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

foreach ($res->PEOPLE_CATALOG->PEOPLE as $PEOPLE) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$PEOPLE->PEOPLE_NAME[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOPLE->PEOPLE[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOPLE->PERSON_TYPE[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOPLE->DESCRIPTION[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOPLE->ID[0]."</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

**Получаю сообщение об ошибке:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
> foreach() in /test/ClassPeople.php on
> line 261

**261 строка:**

> foreach ($res->PEOPLE_CATALOG->PEOPLE
> as $PEOPLE) {

**...да и еще! вот, что мне выдает explode():**

> в начале (перед PEOPLE_CATALOG) отображает **string(611)**

Comment: Попробуйте вот так:

`foreach ($res->PEOLPE_CATALOG as $PEOLPE)`

Comment: @ua6xh попробовал, вообще молчит

Comment: у меня даже структура xml похожая как в мануальном примере

Comment: Во-первых, что в $dom?

Во-вторых, скорее всего - ничего, потому что у вас XML не валидный (посмотрите на последний PEOPLE, нет открывающего <PEOPLE>)

Ps> в качестве догадки: warnings не показываются, да?

Comment: @klopp в $dom:

    $xmlData - здесь XML загружаемый через форму на странице
    
    $xmlDataUTF8 = iconv('cp1251','utf-8', $xmlData);
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($xmlDataUTF8);

XML поправил, на самом деле  XML валидный просто здесь пример составил немного криво но уже исправил в вопросе :)

что касаемо warnings - да не показывается когда делаю по рекомендаци @ua6xh

Comment: без итераций успешно отрабатывает, но соответственно только один блок PEOPLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, передаете ли вы на вход для **`simplexml_load_string()`** объект.
А вообще, вы неправильно выборку делаете.

```
foreach ($res->PEOLPE as $PEOLPE) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$PEOLPE->PEOLPE_NAME[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOLPE->NUM[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOLPE->PERSON_TYPE[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOLPE->DESCRIPTION[0]."</td>
            <td>".$PEOLPE->ID[0]."</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Comment: @VenZell пффффф... Точно! Выборка кривая ))) Спасибо!

Comment: [ideone.com][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/sq8uRN